# repord builder does not display data when in run mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have the following report result when "run" from the designer (report builder).

Please note that even the header strings are empy!!!

[image]

If I save the report on the SSRS server (same query, same sql server) I get:

[image]

An even more weird, if I export to excel from report builder I get:

[image]

How can I get the value displayed in "report builder"

PS: I have the exact same behavior with or without the group and collapsing options

- windows 10 pro x64
- sql serveur express 2016
- report builder 2016

Comment: Are your test and reportserver pointing to the same data source, database?

Comment: @Snowlockk yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Report builder/SSDT cache the data so the query does not need to be run for each preview of the report.

In Report Builder, try rerunning with different parameters, or click the green Refresh circle button on the toolbar.  That should work unless Report Builder expects the same results as before.  For example if your parameter filters are on the tablix, not within dataset query, it will not affect the query results and changing the parameter will not likely refresh the cache.

The above should work for SSDT as well, but you have an additional guaranteed option.  Locate the folder containing your RDL.  You'll also see a .data file with the same name as the .rdl for your report.  Delete the .data file (not the RDL).  Your dataset query will get new data the next time the report is run.

Comment: refresh has no effect, there is no local rdl (the report is on the server). Please note that even the header strings are not displayed in report buider